# YiiBooster Tabs widget content update with ajax call

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using Yii Booster Yii extension for UI. I need to update the content of the tabs using ajax. Using below code I am able to get the content using renderPartial but instead I want to make ajax call and update the content.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'type' => 'tabs',
        'tabs' => array(
                array('label' => 'Home', 'content' => $this->renderPartial('home', NULL, true), 'active' => true),
                array('label' => 'Test', 'items' => array(
                        array('label' => 'Sub Tab 1', 'content' => $this->renderPartial('testpage', NULL, true)),
                        array('label' => 'Sub Tab 2', 'content' => 'some content ')
                )),
        )
    )
);
```

Do I need to use jquery or something else to work with Yii Booster widgets ?. This is the first time I am using php/yii/extensions.

I am a bit confused so Yii Booster has integrated Bootstrap widgets so that they can be used with php. But for client side do I need to use jquery to manipulate bootstrap widgets ?

Are there any tutorials for using Yii Booster, I know the link to yii booster site, but there we just have simple examples nothing related to events, ajax.

Comment: It's not easy. You need get it in complex method: 1st, add handler on show event for tab content, when user click to tab, you need to load through ajax request `testpage`

Comment: @Sergey any links for doing this ? I need to get some start.

Comment: Do you know how to load some text by ajax's methods?

Comment: Yes I know that, but I have not worked with widgets/jquery before. Anyways I got this link [bootstrap-2-tabs-jquery-load-content](http://www.mightywebdeveloper.com/coding/bootstrap-2-tabs-jquery-load-content/). I will try this out.

Comment: I think this will be work, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working. As @Sergey said I need to use 'shown' event. I gave ids to each tab to identify specific tab and load content. Here is the code

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'id' => 'mytabs',
        'type' => 'tabs',
        'tabs' => array(
                array('id' => 'tab1', 'label' => 'Tab 1', 'content' => $this->renderPartial('tab1', null, true), 'active' => true),
                array('id' => 'tab2', 'label' => 'Tab 2', 'content' => 'loading ....'),
                array('id' => 'tab3', 'label' => 'Tab 3', 'content' => 'loading ....'),
        ),
        'events'=>array('shown'=>'js:loadContent')
    )
);?>
```

We have 3 tabs, the content will be loaded using loadContent javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadContent(e){

    var tabId = e.target.getAttribute("href");

    var ctUrl = ''; 

    if(tabId == '#tab1') {
        ctUrl = 'url to get tab 1 content';
    } else if(tabId == '#tab2') {
        ctUrl = 'url to get tab 2 content';
    } else if(tabId == '#tab3') {
        ctUrl = 'url to get tab 3 content';
    }

    if(ctUrl != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url      : ctUrl,
            type     : 'POST',
            dataType : 'html',
            cache    : false,
            success  : function(html)
            {
                jQuery(tabId).html(html);
            },
            error:function(){
                    alert('Request failed');
            }
        });
    }

    preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Here we get the target, that should be the anchor element of the tab that we clicked, get the href value which should be the id that we configured. Decide the url based on this id, load content and update the div's. The id of div's are the same as href.

**I haven't found way to load content of the initial active tab, there should be way to fire loadContent function, for now I have used renderPartial to get the content instead**

Answer (score 1):

I extended the TbTabs class with @Abdullahs example. It's tested with [YiiBooster](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiibooster/), but should work with other Bootstrap plugins as well.

Usage:

```
$this->widget(
    'ext.ajaxTabs.widgets.ajaxTabs',
    array(
         'reload' => true, // Reload the tab content each time a tab is clicked. Delete this line to load it only once.
         'tabs' => array(
             array(
                 'label' => 'Static',
                 'content' => 'Static content'
             ),
             array(
                 'label' => 'Static rendered',
                 'content' => $this->renderPartial('index', null, true),
             ),
             // And finally AJAX:
             array(
                 'label' => 'AJAX',
                 'content' => 'loading ....',
                 'linkOptions' => array('data-tab-url' => Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/'))
             )
         ),
    )
);
```

/protected/extensions/ajaxTabs/widget/ajaxTabs.php:

```
<?php

Yii::import('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs');

class ajaxTabs extends TbTabs
{
    /**
     * @var bool Reload the tab content each time the tab is clicked. Default: load only once
     */
    public $reload = false;

    public function run()
    {
        $id = $this->id;

        /** @var CClientScript $cs */
        $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
        $cs->registerScript(
            __CLASS__ . '#' . $id . '_ajax', '
                function TbTabsAjax(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var $eTarget = $(e.target);
                    var $tab = $($eTarget.attr("href"));
                    var ctUrl = $eTarget.data("tab-url");

                    if (ctUrl != "" && ctUrl !== undefined) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: ctUrl,
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "html",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (html) {
                                $tab.html(html);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("Request failed");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if(' . ($this->reload ? 0 : 1) . '){
                        $eTarget.data("tab-url", "");
                    }
                    return false;
                }'
        );
        $this->events['shown'] = 'js:TbTabsAjax';

        parent::run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a new version to loadContent

```
function loadContent(e){
var targetUrl = e.target.getAttribute('data-tab-url');
var contentID = e.target.getAttribute('href');
$(contentID).load(targetUrl, function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs(); //reinitialize tabs
});
e.preventDefault();
return false;}
```